# Car python script stopped working when I edited part of the moldel

Tags: python

I recently used a car python script and tweaked it to work, but as soon as I edited the front part of the car, it stopped working. there is a working car in the blend file attached.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8TTcNitjst6dVV1LWllU1drZmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for future blend uploads for more permanent hosting.

Comment: I assume you are using the blender game engine?

Comment: yes I am using the BGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm I figured out the problem. I checked the other car and realized I didn't connect a logic circuit to the visibility blocks of the wheels.